# Divide and conquer algorithm to find points beneath certain (x, y) coordinates

Tags: algorithms, divide-and-conquer

Let's say you have a bunch of points on a cartesian plane. For a few of these points you would like to find how many of the other points lie within their (x, y) coordinate, see below for an example:

[image]

I'm trying to solve this for a school assignment and I haven't been able to find any existing algorithms to do some research on. Does anyone have some existing algorithms to solve this and could list them?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you're looking for divide an conquer, does dividing the points in half by $x$ or $y$ coordinate help? What would be a base case?

Comment: What does "within their (x,y) coordinate" mean?  The picture didn't help me.  I encourage you to edit the question to clarify the problem statement, and address the feedback from ryan.

Comment: Please add a reference to the original problem.

Comment: This looks like a problem from an ongoing programming contest.

Comment: @D.W. I meant such that the x and y of other points are both smaller than it's own x and y

Comment: @James what have you tried so far? Consider splitting the elements in half on their $x$ coordinate. If we have two sets $A$, $B$, where $A$'s $x$ coord is less than $B$'s, then you already know all elements in $A$ will be "contained" in $B$'s $x$ coordinate, so you only have to worry about $y$ coordinates in between them. Maybe this could help you? You still need to consider base cases.